# AStar with a nested graph structure

Tags: boost, graph-theory, a-star

I have a graph (current a directed acyclic graph) implemented using boost a*. The graph itself is somewhat spatially inconsistent, in that the graph is comprised of multiple zones which within each zone, the coordinates make sense spatially, but between zones coordinates do not accurately reflect spatial distance. So within zones, euclidean distance works as a distance metric, but when considering nodes in two separate zones, euclidean distance doesn't. This is impossible to rectify as well, since the graph is for a MUD, which does not have a rigid coordinate structure.

One solution to this is to model the path from a->b as a series of movements through zones, find the fastest route within each respective zone, and then combine these paths into a final one.

So my question: is there a way to have this sort of "nested graph" structure, or am I going to have to chunk the problem manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably take a look at the concept of [subgraph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/subgraph.html) in Boost.Graph library. Actual examples there use boost::[adjacency_list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html).

I guess your starting point would be to create a supergraph; then create a subgraph per each zone, populate them with vertices. The hardest part is probably to add all edges of such graph.

As for distance map for the graph, you do not have to store it on the graph; it can be an external property_map or even a functor which computes the distance dynamically.

Comment: Do you know if this would handle the distance metrics via the global graph or would it handle it from the coordinates of the subgraph? It isn't obvious from the documentation. By this I mean subgraph A would have coordinates in the range of x=(-200,200), y=(-200,200), but subzone C may have the same coordinates. There is no single giant map. So going from zone A->C, would the goals be calculated as coordinates in A and in C, or would the subgraphs be solved first?

Comment: First of all, BGL knows nothing about your coordinates. A* only reasons in terms of edges and their weights. So the first question you need to answer: how you define edges within a cluster? Second, how you define edges (possible paths) between clusters. Finally, you chose how to inform BGL on weights associated with edges. BGL gives you plenty of options how to pass edge weights to a specific algorithm. You can have it as a number of edge, you can pass an associative container (like map<edge_descriptor,double>) or you can define your edge as a functor.